# How to remove TabItem indicator bottom padding?

Tags: android, xml

How to remove bottom padding of TabItem or its indicator, so that it would appear totally on the bottom of toolbar?

[image]

My xml layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/menu_fragment_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:background="@color/app_font_dark"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_tablayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_indicator_color"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="30dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="30dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle"
            />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have tried setting bottom margin and padding of `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` to 0dp but it doesn't seem to take effect. I'm using support library v26.0.0-alpha1 and device with API 25.
I'm adding TabItems dynamically by calling

`tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Some long text"));`

Comment: Officially toolbar height is `56dp`. Also set `TabLayout` height to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use match_parent height in TabLayout as shown below

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_menu_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_indicator_color"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="30dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="30dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle"
        />
```

Comment: Oh god, how could've I miss that. It worked, thanks!

Comment: @Tuby So didn't you notice my comment ?

Comment: @Piyush I did, but you didn't post it as answer so I took whats there. Thanks!

Comment: @Piyush Great work, try to put solutions as answer so user can see and use your solutions  :)

Answer (score 5):

I have update to `androidx`, change height like this `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

My Code is below

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tl_local_category"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
If `tabPaddingStart/tabPaddingEnd/tabPaddingTop/tabPaddingBottom` `0dp` not working than try with `-1dp` also.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_forum_tab"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_indicator_color"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle" />
```

Comment: That didn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

try this
create a theme like this

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
<item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
<item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
<item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
<item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
<item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
<item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
<item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
<item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
```

**set this theme to your tablayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/main_menu_tablayout"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="start"         
      app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
      app:tabMode="scrollable"      
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextStyle"
        />
```